# Why rails in production env display backtrace if No route matches error occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails 3.1 app in production env display backtrace if No route matches error occurs.

No status code is rendered and instead of showing the 500.html, it displays the error itself.

Comment: Hard to say without any more context. Does it happen on every url that doesn't match? Or just the ones covered by a resoures?

Comment: not just on all routes, but only few ones.

Answer (score 0):

If by mistake you have this in your production.rb

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

either remove it or set it to false

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```